# TestHost generating Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-testhost

I have written some integration tests using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost, But when I try to get a message as Invalid URI.

I can create TestServer successfully and able to create a client. But when I call an API using the client it says invalid URI. The URL created by TestHost is http://localhost/ and there is nothing look wrong in that URL.

I am not able to understand how could this URL be wrong. There is no other localhost website running in my machine also.

When I run my web API it's run on this URL Http:\localhost:5000 and set that as base address in my test project but it still throws the same error.

This my code to build Test Server

```
public MongoDbFixture()
        {
            var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                   .UseContentRoot(GetContentRootPath())
                   .UseEnvironment("Test")
                   .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(GetContentRootPath())
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Test.json")
                   .Build())
                   .UseStartup<Startup>();  // Uses Start up class from your API Host project to configure the test server

            _testServer = new TestServer(builder);
            Client = _testServer.CreateClient();
            //Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/");
            AuthClient = _testServer.CreateClient();
            //AuthenticateClient();
            //AddPromptQuestions();
            //SetupGoogleTranslationService();
        }
```

This is a code to make a request.

```
 public async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    //var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", "kunal.ahmedabad@gmail.com"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "Password123!") });
                    var content = new StringContent("{email:'test@test.com',password:'Integration#85'}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var response = await Client.PostAsync(new Uri("api/Accounts/Login"), content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    //var token = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OkResult>();
                    var newToken = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(newToken, new { Token = "", IsPhoneNumberConfirmed = "" });
                    token = tokenResponse.Token;
                    //token = newToken.Split(":")[1].Replace("\"", "").Replace("}", "");//todo:add better logic to read token.    
                    return token;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return "";
        }
```

I am not sure what is a valid URL, but this setup was working earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
new Uri("api/Accounts/Login")
```

To:

```
new Uri("api/Accounts/Login", UriKind.Relative)
```

Comment: wow...that worked. is it some new change in the framework as it was working earlier without this.

Comment: so earlier we were using string instead of Uri, we replaced string with URI as FxCop was showing a warning on using string type. I should have tested at that time, it would save my day.